# How to highlight Node and it's Label in vis.js?

Tags: jquery, vis.js-network

My objective is to change the node's label background into red and the label is white when the node's is exiting after search. What is happen now the label seems gone.

[image]

My reference & complete code is here [vis.js search function](https://www.programmersought.com/article/63267272523/)

I already follow the code and works but need some modification on the stated issue above.
Below are the modification part that I do.

```
$("#btnSearch").on('click',function () {
    for (var i = 0;i<allNodes.length;i++){
        if (allNodes[i].ip.indexOf($("#inputSearch").val()) >=0  && $("#inputSearch").val() != ''){
            allNodes[i].color = {
                border: "#406897"
            };
            allNodes[i].label = { // Here is the additional code
                background: "#FF0000",
                color: "#FFFFFF"
            };
            allNodes[i].shapeProperties = {
                useBorderWithImage: true
            };
        }else{
            delete allNodes[i].color;
            delete  allNodes[i].shapeProperties;
        }
    }
    new vis.Network(container, data, options);
});
```

Comment: Hi, use `.font` i.e : `allNodes[i].font = { background: "#FF0000",color: "#FFFFFF"};`

Comment: Hi @Swati , if you don't mind, can you assist on my next problem regarding vis.js. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124530/how-to-clear-reset-refresh-vis-js-function-for-selectnode-or-selectedge`