# How to change node image in vis.js when node clicked?

Tags: jquery, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to replicate script in vis.js library for grey node when clicked, it is successfully but that is actually for `shape` type. but my case is I am using `image` type. What happen is the image is not change. How to implement below code for my case (using image).

Let say I have 2 images (Image_A and Image_B), Image_A is for default color image, Image_B is grey image. So when clicked at specific node, the node will use Image_A and other is Image_B. When clicked outside all nodes will use Image_A.

Example only:

[image]

Source link: [Grey out other node](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/exampleApplications/neighbourhoodHighlight.html)

```
var network;
var allNodes;
var highlightActive = false;
var nodes;

function redrawAll() {
    var allNodes = [{
        id: 1,
        label: "Node A_1",
        image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-a-icon-4.png"
    },{
        id: 2,
        label: "Node A_2",
        image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-a-icon-4.png"
    },{
        id: 3,
        label: "Node B_1",
        image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-b-icon-png-23.png"
    },{
        id: 4,
        label: "Node B_2",
        image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-b-icon-png-23.png"
    },
    ];
    // Create edge data array
    var allEdges = [
        { id: "1_2", from: 1, to: 2 },
        { id: "2_3", from: 2, to: 3 },
        { id: "2_4", from: 2, to: 4 },
        { id: "4_1", from: 4, to: 1 }
    ]
    var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
    var nodes = new vis.DataSet(allNodes);
    var edges = new vis.DataSet(allEdges);
    var data = { nodes: nodes, edges: edges };
    var options = {};
    network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

    // get a JSON object
    allNodes = nodes.get({ returnType: "Object" });
    network.on("click", neighbourhoodHighlight);
}

function neighbourhoodHighlight(params) {
    // if something is selected:
    if (params.nodes.length > 0) {
        highlightActive = true;
        var i, j;
        var selectedNode = params.nodes[0];
        var degrees = 2;
  
        // mark all nodes as hard to read.
        for (var nodeId in allNodes) {
            allNodes[nodeId].color = "rgba(200,200,200,0.5)";
            if (allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel === undefined) {
                allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel = allNodes[nodeId].label;
                allNodes[nodeId].label = undefined;
            }
        }
        var connectedNodes = network.getConnectedNodes(selectedNode);
        var allConnectedNodes = [];
    
        // get the second degree nodes
        for (i = 1; i < degrees; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < connectedNodes.length; j++) {
                allConnectedNodes = allConnectedNodes.concat(network.getConnectedNodes(connectedNodes[j]));
            }
        }
  
        // all second degree nodes get a different color and their label back
        for (i = 0; i < allConnectedNodes.length; i++) {
            allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].color = "rgba(150,150,150,0.75)";
            if (allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
                allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].label = allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel;
                allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel = undefined;
            }
        }
    
        // all first degree nodes get their own color and their label back
        for (i = 0; i < connectedNodes.length; i++) {
            allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].color = undefined;
            if (allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
                allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].label = allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel;
                allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel = undefined;
            }
        }
    
        // the main node gets its own color and its label back.
        allNodes[selectedNode].color = undefined;
        if (allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
            allNodes[selectedNode].label = allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel;
            allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel = undefined;
        }
    }
    else if (highlightActive === true) {
        // reset all nodes
        for (var nodeId in allNodes) {
            allNodes[nodeId].color = undefined;
            if (allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
                allNodes[nodeId].label = allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel;
                allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel = undefined;
            }
        }
        highlightActive = false;
    }
  
    // transform the object into an array
    var updateArray = [];
    for (nodeId in allNodes) {
        if (allNodes.hasOwnProperty(nodeId)) {
            updateArray.push(allNodes[nodeId]);
        }
    }
    nodes.update(updateArray);
}

redrawAll();
```

Comment: Hi, what is `nodesDataset` in your code  ? I am getting undefined there .. Can you make this runnable ?

Comment: Hi, so sorry, I have update the code, `nodesDataset` is changed to `nodes`, already check also whole code is workable in my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `shape :"image"` to display node as images. Then , to make image blur i have use `opacity` instead of `color` . So , whenever you need to blur other images use `allNodes[nodeId].opacity = any value` same for all other nodes.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var network;
var allNodes;
var highlightActive = false;
var nodes;

function redrawAll() {
  allNodes = [{
    id: 1,
    label: "Node A_1",
    shape: "image", //added shape..to show image.. in nodes..
    image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-a-icon-4.png"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: "Node A_2",
    shape: "image",
    image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-a-icon-4.png"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    label: "Node B_1",
    shape: "image",
    image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-b-icon-png-23.png"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    label: "Node B_2",
    shape: "image",
    image: "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-b-icon-png-23.png"
  }, ];
  // Create edge data array
  allEdges = [{
      id: "1_2",
      from: 1,
      to: 2
    },
    {
      id: "2_3",
      from: 2,
      to: 3
    },
    {
      id: "1_3",
      from: 1,
      to: 3
    },
    {
      id: "4_1",
      from: 4,
      to: 1
    }
  ]
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  nodes = new vis.DataSet(allNodes);
  var edges = new vis.DataSet(allEdges);
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  //just added some styles..
  var options = {
    edges: {
      color: {
        color: '#CCC',
        highlight: '#A22'
      },
      width: 3,
      length: 275,
      hoverWidth: .05
    }
  };
  network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

  //get a JSON object
  allNodes = nodes.get({
    returnType: "Object"
  });
  network.on("click", neighbourhoodHighlight);
}

function neighbourhoodHighlight(params) {
  // if something is selected:
  if (params.nodes.length > 0) {
    highlightActive = true;
    var i, j;
    var selectedNode = params.nodes[0];
    var degrees = 2;

    // mark all nodes as hard to read.
    for (var nodeId in allNodes) {
      allNodes[nodeId].opacity = 0.2; //change to opacity..
      if (allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel === undefined) {
        allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel = allNodes[nodeId].label;
        allNodes[nodeId].label = undefined;
      }
    }
    var connectedNodes = network.getConnectedNodes(selectedNode);
    var allConnectedNodes = [];

    // get the second degree nodes
    for (i = 1; i < degrees; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < connectedNodes.length; j++) {
        allConnectedNodes = allConnectedNodes.concat(network.getConnectedNodes(connectedNodes[j]));
      }
    }
    // all second degree nodes get a different opacity and their label back
    for (i = 0; i < allConnectedNodes.length; i++) {
      allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].opacity = 0.10
      if (allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
        allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].label = allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel;
        allNodes[allConnectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel = undefined;
      }
    }

    // all first degree nodes get their own opacity and their label back
    for (i = 0; i < connectedNodes.length; i++) {
      allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].opacity = undefined;
      if (allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
        allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].label = allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel;
        allNodes[connectedNodes[i]].hiddenLabel = undefined;
      }
    }

    // the main node gets its own opacity and its label back.
    allNodes[selectedNode].opacity = undefined;
    if (allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
      allNodes[selectedNode].label = allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel;
      allNodes[selectedNode].hiddenLabel = undefined;
    }
  } else if (highlightActive === true) {
    // reset all nodes
    for (var nodeId in allNodes) {
      allNodes[nodeId].opacity = undefined;
      if (allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel !== undefined) {
        allNodes[nodeId].label = allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel;
        allNodes[nodeId].hiddenLabel = undefined;
      }
    }
    highlightActive = false;
  }

  // transform the object into an array
  var updateArray = [];
  for (nodeId in allNodes) {
    if (allNodes.hasOwnProperty(nodeId)) {
      updateArray.push(allNodes[nodeId]);
    }
  }
  nodes.update(updateArray);
}

redrawAll();
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>

<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have no idea that just change `color` to `opacity`.